# tenacity.RetryError: RetryError[<Future at 0x7f89bc35eb90 state=finished raised AuthenticationError>]

Tags: python, streamlit, openai-api, llama-index

I am trying to deploy an app made with streamlit (using also streamlit_chat and streamlit_authenticator). This app is making use of llama-index to create a query engine incorporating chatgpt api. When I state "streamlit run app.py" in my computer, everything works fine, but when I deploy it the following error raises:

```
    2023-06-07 16:45:28.682 Uncaught app exception

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 382, in __call__

    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/embeddings/openai.py", line 106, in get_embedding

    return openai.Embedding.create(input=[text], engine=engine)["data"][0]["embedding"]

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_resources/embedding.py", line 33, in create

    response = super().create(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py", line 149, in create

    ) = cls.__prepare_create_request(

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py", line 106, in __prepare_create_request

    requestor = api_requestor.APIRequestor(

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 138, in __init__

    self.api_key = key or util.default_api_key()

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/util.py", line 186, in default_api_key

    raise openai.error.AuthenticationError(

openai.error.AuthenticationError: No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = <API-KEY>', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=<API-KEY>). If your API key is stored in a file, you can point the openai module at it with 'openai.api_key_path = <PATH>'. You can generate API keys in the OpenAI web interface. See https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys for details.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 561, in _run_script

    self._session_state.on_script_will_rerun(rerun_data.widget_states)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/state/safe_session_state.py", line 68, in on_script_will_rerun

    self._state.on_script_will_rerun(latest_widget_states)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/state/session_state.py", line 482, in on_script_will_rerun

    self._call_callbacks()

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/state/session_state.py", line 495, in _call_callbacks

    self._new_widget_state.call_callback(wid)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/state/session_state.py", line 247, in call_callback

    callback(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/app/bajoquetumgpt/docsv2.py", line 35, in generate_answer

    response = query_engine.query(user_msg)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/indices/query/base.py", line 20, in query

    return self._query(str_or_query_bundle)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/query_engine/retriever_query_engine.py", line 139, in _query

    nodes = self._retriever.retrieve(query_bundle)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/indices/base_retriever.py", line 21, in retrieve

    return self._retrieve(str_or_query_bundle)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/token_counter/token_counter.py", line 78, in wrapped_llm_predict

    f_return_val = f(_self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/indices/vector_store/retrievers.py", line 62, in _retrieve

    self._service_context.embed_model.get_agg_embedding_from_queries(

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/embeddings/base.py", line 83, in get_agg_embedding_from_queries

    query_embeddings = [self.get_query_embedding(query) for query in queries]

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/embeddings/base.py", line 83, in <listcomp>

    query_embeddings = [self.get_query_embedding(query) for query in queries]

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/embeddings/base.py", line 72, in get_query_embedding

    query_embedding = self._get_query_embedding(query)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/embeddings/openai.py", line 223, in _get_query_embedding

    return get_embedding(query, engine=engine)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 289, in wrapped_f

    return self(f, *args, **kw)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 379, in __call__

    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 326, in iter

    raise retry_exc from fut.exception()

tenacity.RetryError: RetryError[<Future at 0x7f89bc35eb90 state=finished raised AuthenticationError>]
```

The code is private but I can show the part where the authenticator and the query engine are used:

```
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader
with open('./config.yaml') as file:
    config = yaml.load(file, Loader=SafeLoader)

authenticator = stauth.Authenticate(
    config['credentials'],
    config['cookie']['name'],
    config['cookie']['key'],
    config['cookie']['expiry_days'],
    config['preauthorized']
)
name, authentication_status, username = authenticator.login('Login', 'main')
print(username, name, authentication_status)
if authentication_status:
    authenticator.logout('Logout', 'main')
    st.write(f'Welcome *{name}*')
elif authentication_status == False:
    st.error('Username/password is incorrect')
elif authentication_status == None:
    st.warning('Please enter your username and password')
FIRST_OUTPUT="""Hello!"""

if authentication_status:
    API_KEY = config['credentials']['usernames'][username].get('openaiapi', "")
    st.text("""First text""")
    text_input_container = st.empty()
    if API_KEY=="":
        API_KEY = text_input_container.text_input(label='Introduce your OpenAI API Key:', label_visibility = 'hidden', placeholder='Introduce your OpenAI API Key:')
    if API_KEY != "":
        text_input_container.empty()
    os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = API_KEY
```

And it continues as:

```
if API_KEY != '':
        # Load the index from your saved index.json file
        storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir='./storage')
        # load index
        index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)


        query_engine = index.as_query_engine()


        if "history" not in st.session_state:
            st.session_state.history = initial_history
        c = st.expander("Open to see the previous messages!")
        for i, chat in enumerate(st.session_state.history):
            if i < len(st.session_state.history)-6:
                with c:
                    message(**chat, key=str(i)) #unpacking
            else:
                message(**chat, key=str(i)) #unpacking
        st.text_input("You: ", "", key="input_text", on_change = generate_answer)
```

The function generate_answer is:

```
def generate_answer():
    user_msg = st.session_state.input_text
    st.session_state.input_text = ""
    response = query_engine.query(user_msg)
    st.session_state.history.append(
        {"message": user_msg, "is_user":True,
        "avatar_style": "fun-emoji",
        "seed": 4}
    )
    st.session_state.history.append(
        {"message": str(response).strip(), "is_user":False,
        "avatar_style": "bottts-neutral",
        "seed": 36}
    )
```

I would love to receive any help with it.

Answer (score 9):

You are probably setting the API key like this:

```
 os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'YOUR_KEY'
```

The problem here is because you are filling this variable just in your local environment. To send it to OpenAI you have to do something like this:

```
import openai

openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
```

I'll let a piece of my code here to you understand better.

```
from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTVectorStoreIndex, LLMPredictor, ServiceContext, StorageContext, load_index_from_storage
from langchain import OpenAI
import gradio as gr
import os
import openai

# Here I fill my LOCAL environment variable
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'YOUR_KEY'

def construct_index(directory_path):
    # And here I fill the key to openAI
    openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
    num_outputs = 512

    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0.7, model_name="text-davinci-003", max_tokens=num_outputs))
    
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor)

    docs = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path).load_data()

    index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(docs, service_context=service_context)

    index.storage_context.persist()
    return index
```

That's worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'YOUR_KEY'
```

change this

```
openai.api_key  = "key"
```

to this

Comment: Don't give out your api key.